# Samsung Smart TV on 64bit Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, sdk, 32bit-64bit, samsung-smart-tv

I do know that in the specification of the Smart TV SDK it's written it needs 32-bit system. But, is it possible to somehow run the SDK on 64bit Linux?

Running the adapted eclipse silently fails, no output nor window is created.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible! you just have to "cheat" Eclipse, using Java RE 32 bits in your 64 bits system. The way of doing that is changing the file "eclipse.ini" adding that:  -vm
/opt/sun-jdk-1.6.0.02/bin/java (changing the path to your java 32 bits). Look at this page: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Linux_Example.

I hope it works for you!:)